# Unir dos QuerySet de modelos diferentes en Django

Tags: ajax, json, django, serialización, django-views

Estoy tratando de hacer una consulta a dos modelos diferentes, que tienen un campo en común. Este es mi fichero `models.py`:

```
class Service(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # otros atributos

class Visa(models.Model):
    # atributos de la clase Visa


class Passport(models.Model):
    # atributos de la clase Passport
```

Y en la vista tengo (`views.py`):

```
class SearchView(generic.FormView):
    form_class = forms.SearchForm
    # otros atributos

    def form_valid(self, form):
        search = form.search_status()
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            data = {
                'data': search,
            }
            return JsonResponse(data)
        else:
            return super().form_valid(form)
```

Y esta es mi archivo `forms.py`:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    search = forms.CharField()

    def search_status(self):
        search = self.cleaned_data['search']
        visa_result = models.Visa.objects.filter(
            Q(client__ci__exact=search) & Q(status='active')
        )
        passport_result = models.Passport.objects.filter(
            Q(client__ci__exact=search) & Q(status='active')
        )
        result = []
        for v in visa_result:
            result.append(v)
        for p in passport_result:
            result.append(p)
        return result
```

La consulta la realiza bien, pero en la visa, cuando va a re tornarme un JSON da el siguiente error:

```
TypeError: Object of type 'Visa' is not JSON serializable
```

Como puedo hacer que mis modelos sean serializables?

Comment: te sugiero usar DjangoJSONEncoder

Comment: from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
json.dumps(mydict, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)

Comment: puedes hacer tambien `model_to_dict()` pero depende de las acciones que vas a hacer

Answer (score 0):

Hay algunos campos en los modelos que no pueden ser serializados por defecto, para eso necesitas encoders especiales como se menciona en los comentarios pero que a mi parecer son un poco limitados.

Veo que solo llamas a la función `search_status` cuando es AJAX así que con esto debería bastar:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    search = forms.CharField()

    def search_status(self):
        search = self.cleaned_data['search']
        visa_result = models.Visa.objects.filter(
            Q(client__ci__exact=search) & Q(status='active')
        )
        passport_result = models.Passport.objects.filter(
            Q(client__ci__exact=search) & Q(status='active')
        )
        result = []
        for v in visa_result:
            # Los campos que necesites
            result.append({
                'v_id': v.id,
                'v_otro_campo': v.otro_campo,
                'v_relacion_id': v.relacion.id # una relación a otro modelo
                'v_relacion_nombre': v.relacion.nombre # la misma relación, otro campo
            })

        for p in passport_result:
            # Los campos que necesites
            result.append({
                'p_id': p.id,
                'p_otro_campo': p.otro_campo
            })
        return result
```

Ahora al llamar al a función desde tu vista no debería haber problemas. Es probable que necesites modificar la función que esté recibiendo estos campos para usar los nombres correctos (`p_id`, `v_id`, etc.).

La función que recibe del `JsonResponse` debería ver algo como esto:

```
[
    {"v_id": 1, "v_otro_campo": "foo", "v_relacion_id": 5, "v_relacion_nombre": "Mr. Foo"},
    {"p_id": 100, "p_otro_campo": "bar"},
    ...
]
```